# Django, CSP: How to activate Nonce in scripts for Admin pages

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

At my page scripts are only executed, when the nonce tag is included (because of CSP settings).

That causes at the admin pages, that scripts are not working.

Therefore I am overwriting now all the admin templates, for example from:

```
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/nav_sidebar.js' %}" defer></script>
```

to

```
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/nav_sidebar.js' %}" nonce="{{request.csp_nonce}}" defer></script>
```

Is there an easier  way to do this?  Deactivate CSP on the admin pages or somehow tell Django to add Nonce to all scripts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok I could also add all script hashes to CSP, that is also working. But maybe there is also another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quickie I just figured out that may help you. It doesn't *fix* the root problem in the original which is resources missing a nonce, but you can add a second reference to the resource that includes the nonce (assumes all your CSP setup is working). Given the example below of `calendar.js`, it'll be referenced in the HTML twice. The first will generate the CSP error, but the second will work. Your console will be a bit messy but all your nonce'd stuff will work again.

1. In your base `templates` directory, add another directory called `admin`
2. There, create a file called `base.html`, i.e. `templates/admin/base.html`. It is in here you'll add additional stuff.

That's it.

The **additional stuff** inside your local `templates/admin/base.html`:

```html
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block extrastyle %}
<script nonce="{{request.csp_nonce}}" src="/static/admin/js/calendar.js"></script>

<!-- whatever else you need with a nonce -->

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @tomk You should reply in comments for those questions applicable to this answer. There probably is but I don't see an easy way to fix all admin page resources without this little bit of manual tweaking.